# Android Notifications: Is there a way to show the notifications individually?

Tags: android, statusbar, android-notification-bar

I am trying to figure out a way to show notifications individually when clicked on the bar.  As it works now, you will see your different icons for each notification listed across the bar, but when you click one, you get the list of all notifications present on the system.  Clicking a notification in that list will launch the intent tied to it.  Is there a way to only show the notification that is directly tied to that notification icon on the initial click from the notification bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to your users to try to click a small icon in the notification bar without pulling down the sliding drawer?

I have not tried this, but I assume that the system does not allow this functionality.
Imagine how frustrating it will be for users to try to click super small icons all grouped together with high precision.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that this is on a tablet in Ice Cream Sandwich.  I am really just trying to lock down one notification in particular.  I want that notification to have different behavior than the rest.

Comment: Oh. So make sure that your when your calling notify() you are passing in a different value for the id. Then once the user selects that notification you can check the id which will tell the difference between notifications and you can act accordingly.